How does an assembler find the offset of a label without knowing the value of the segment register?
I am learning about some simple x86 bootloader code and having some trouble understanding how the assembler (nasm in my case) calculates the offsets of labels.
It is my understanding that a data label like letter below represents the offset of the following byte within the data segment.  It is also my understanding that in an instruction like mov al, [letter], the label is implicitly interpreted as ds:letter.  This means that the assembler needs to know the offset of label within the data segment in order to reference the correct address.
What I don't understand is how the assembler calculates this offset.  To figure out the offset, it would need to know where the start of the data segment is.  But it doesn't know this since it doesn't know the value of ds at the assembly stage.  So how is the offset calculated?
[org 0x7c00]
bits 16

; initialise data segment register
mov ax, 0
mov ds, ax

; print letter
mov al, [letter]
mov ah, 0x0e
int 0x10

end:
jmp $


; data label
letter:
db 'A'


times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa

This code prints the letter A as expected.  But I note that if I change ds to some other value, say 10, it doesn't print anything.  So clearly the assembler is calculating the offset independently of the value of ds (so there's no guarantee ds:letter would reach the right address) -- I just don't know how it's calculating it.

A label is a relocateable symbol within a given section. Relocateable just means that depending on the linker, the assembler's view of the section may be incomplete so the linker may apply an adjustment. (When you assemble with nasm -f bin then a linker internal to NASM is used.) Other than the relocateable part, the label just represents an offset (into a section/segment). In NASM no type, size, or segment information is stored alongside the label's name, offset (in a section), and section (to make it relocateable). You can misuse a label with a "wrong" segment, NASM will be none the wiser.

"This means that the assembler needs to know the offset of label within the data segment in order to reference the correct address." Correct, this is done in two steps: First there is the possibility of a non-zero org, or start= or vstart= attribute in the multi-section -f bin output format. All of these together determine the base address of a section. Then the assembler emits data bytes (progbits) or space reservations (nobits) into the section, eg mov ax, 0 gives three bytes and mov ds, ax gives two bytes. The assembler keeps a count of how many bytes (1/2)

(2/2) it has emitted yet into the current section. When it sees a label: (or equivalently label: equ $) it assigns the current count as the "offset" part to the label, though as mentioned this is relative to the section start.

@ecm Okay so if I'm understanding correctly, all offsets (regardless of the segment) are calculated from the start of my program (plus 0x7c00)? But in that case, wouldn't it be impossible for the data segment to ever be different from the code segment, since the offsets for both are calculated relative to the same point?

"all offsets (regardless of the segment) are calculated from the start of my program (plus 0x7c00)?" No, only offsets within the same/first section. If you add a section FOO vstart=256 then labels in this section have a different base calculated for them. You can address the same section using more than one segreg, or have different segregs point at different sections. However, in your toy example the assembler can be said to expect cs = ds = 0 because you are using code and data mixed into the same section.

@ecm okay I think I'm getting it.  If I could ask one more thing just to make sure I understand, if I were to add section FOO vstart=256 right before my definition of the data label, what would I need to set my segment register(s) to to make the code work? And would I have to alter the mov al, [letter] command in any way (say appending a segment register to letter)?

If letter: is the first line in the FOO section it would be at the start of the section. So due to the vstart=256 writing mov al, [letter] would be encoded with the address 256 + 0. If you want that to access the variable, then your ds (or es or whatever segreg you want to use) would have to point such that it => (segment points to) memory starting 16 paragraphs before the location of the variable. (You may want align=16 in the section directive to make this possible with 86 Mode para-aligned segments.) The mov al would work as-is with the correct ds, but could use es etc also.

Boot loader code would be built as a  single section image, like a  .COM program, where it is expected to set cs and ds to the same value.. For MASM, this would be "tiny" model. I don't know what NASM would use. The label offsets are based off the org statement.

Thanks both of you.  I believe I have a better picture of how this works now and I've figured out where my confusion was coming from.

With help from users ecm and rcgldr, I've figured out the source of my confusion, so I'll summarise the answer to my question below in case others have the same confusion.
My mistake was to think that the segment registers DEFINE where a segment starts, and that the assembler therefore would need to know the value of a segment register before calculating the offset.
This is not technically accurate.  When we write our program, we need to have some plan about where we want the segments to start, and where the bytes of our program should reside relative to the start of these segments.  That is, we should already know the segment and program layout before assigning segment registers and offsets in the program.
So the offsets we assign are not dependent on the values we assign to the segment registers, but, rather, the offsets we assign AND the values we give the segment registers are BOTH dependent on our plan for the segment layout which we already drew up.  It is up to us to give both of these the right values in order to implement our plan and allow the processor to get to the addresses we intended.  We assign to the segment registers to get the starting addresses of the segments right, and we assign offsets using various directives like org and section to get the positions of the bytes within the segments right.

In the case of DOS 6.22 or Windows using MBR, this is the sequence. Partition sector is read at 0000:7C00, it relocates itself to 0000:0600, looks for the first active partition and reads in it's boot sector into 0000:7C00. The boot sector then loads IO.SYS (DOS) or NTLDR (Windows XP) and jumps to it. For the partition sector, since code references are PC relative, relocation is not an issue. Directives like org, offset, or hard coded offsets are used to access relocated data.

@rcgldr For MS-DOS the boot sector loaders actually only need to read the first 1536 Bytes (MS-DOS v6) or 2048 Bytes (MS-DOS v7), as I documented in https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/ldosboot.htm#protocol-sector-msdos6 This initial loader, also called msload, takes care to load the remaining file data from the file system. msload is loaded to 70h:0 and entered with cs:ip equal to 70h:0, relocates itself to near the top of the Low Memory Area, and loads msbio (the next module) to 70h:0 again. Other DOS versions may differ in the load details or next stages.

@ecm - My prior comment is about the MBR partition sector (which originally had 4 partition entries), which finds an active partition and reads in the partition root sector, which in turn reads in IO.SYS or MSDOS.SYS at 0070:0000.

@rcgldr I didn't disagree about the MBR, just that it is inaccurate to say "the boot sector ... loads IO.SYS" when only the msload portion at the beginning of the BIO kernel file can/must be/is loaded by the boot sector loader.
